# Downloading a file

Tags: plugins

I want to redirect user to download a video file from main website to my blog, my main website isn't using WordPress but my blog is.
Is there a way to create such redirects to a random post to download that video file

Comment: To a specific post? Yes, but you'd have to set up the redirect on your main website.

Comment: To a random post? There's no built-in 'choose a random post' in WordPress I don't think but it's probably not too hard to add. But surely you don't want a random post, you want the post that has the video?